# Having trouble with a Button on google Sheets (Automated email sending)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, button

So, here i am again
My last code is now running just fine, as intended (Thanks, everyone~) and now i'm trying to use a button to make it easier(Just a click at the button at google sheets, instead of doing it at AppScript)

So, i'll now show you how my last code was like:

```
// Esta constante é escrita na coluna C para linhas nas quais um e-mail
// foi enviado com sucesso.

function unknown() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();// Obtém a planilha ativa do google sheets
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("cadastros");// Obtém a folha de cálculo com o nome  "cadastros"
  var rg = sh.getDataRange();// Obtém a faixa de dados na folha de trabalho
  var vs = rg.getValues();  // Obtém os valores da faixa de dados
  const esh = ss.getSheetByName("email");  // Obtém a folha de cálculo com o nome "email"
  var message = esh.getRange("A4").getValue();  // Obtém o conteúdo da célula A4 na planilha "email"
  var t = esh.getRange("A2").getValue();  // Obtém o conteúdo da célula A2 na planilha "email"

  for (var i = 1; i < vs.length; i++) {  // Itera sobre as linhas da faixa de dados a partir da segunda linha (índice 1)
    var row = vs[i];    // Obtém os valores da linha(row) atual
    var name = row[0];
    var emailDestination = row[1]; 
    var emailSent = row[2]; 
    if (emailDestination && emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) { 
      var subjectTemplate = t;//Reinicializar o template antes cada troca (Replace)
      var subject = subjectTemplate.replace("<nome>", name);
      var message2 = message.replace("<nome>", name); // troca o placeholder <nome> pelo nome que está na planilha
      sendEmailWithLogo(emailDestination, subject, message2, logoUrl= "https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E12AQHwckJ-hv-0rg/article-cover_image-shrink_600_2000/0/1632191739115?e=2147483647&v=beta&t=CbEz6-6qwHRuHy65RGXc2BOzy7Fix_eRlh_3dZFut2Q"); // o email é colocado junto com a logo (logoUrl)
      ss.getSheetByName("cadastros").getRange(1 + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT); // a coluna com o status(emailsent) é marcada com EMAIL_SENT, evitando duplicatas
      Logger.log("Email enviado a " + emailDestination + " Com sucesso!") // No log do console é avisado se o email foi enviado para os que indivíduos sem status de EMAIL_SENT na planilha
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
    else {
      Logger.log("No new email to send!")
    }
  }
}
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';

// Função principal para enviar e-mails
function sendEmail() {
  // URL do logo a ser incluído no e-mail (Lembrar de usar uma logo em .png)
  var logoUrl = "https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E12AQHwckJ-hv-0rg/article-cover_image-shrink_600_2000/0/1632191739115?e=2147483647&v=beta&t=CbEz6-6qwHRuHy65RGXc2BOzy7Fix_eRlh_3dZFut2Q";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Obter o endereço do email
  var dataRange = ss.getSheetByName("cadastros").getDataRange();

  // Faz com que seja obtido o assunto e a mensagem do email (A2/A4)
  var subjectTemplate = ss.getSheetByName("email").getRange("A2").getValue(); // Refere-se à parte de Título do assunto, nos sheets posicionado em A2
  var message = ss.getSheetByName("email").getRange("A4").getValue(); // Refere-se à parte de e-mail, nos sheets posicionado em A4

  // Obtem valores para cada linha no alcance determinado
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  // Loop através das linhas da planilha "cadastros"
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var name = row[0]; // Primeira coluna do planilha (Nome)
    var emailDestination = row[1]; // Segunda coluna da planilha (Email)
    var emailSent = row[2]; // Terceira Coluna da planilha (status)

    // Se o email estiver vazio, dá um break
    if (emailDestination == "") {
      break;
    }

    // Verifica se o e-mail ainda não foi enviado
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {
      
      var subject = subjectTemplate.replace("<nome>", name);
      var message2 = message.replace("<nome>", name);// Troca a marcação <nome> pelo nome que está escrito na planilha


      // Envie o e-mail com o logotipo
      sendEmailWithLogo(emailDestination, subject, message2, logoUrl);

      // Marque a coluna 'Status' como 'EMAIL_SENT', evitando duplicatas
      ss.getSheetByName("cadastros").getRange(1 + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);

      // Registre que o e-mail foi enviado com sucesso no log/console
      Logger.log("Email enviado para " + emailDestination + " com sucesso!");

      // Garanta que a célula seja atualizada imediatamente, caso o script seja interrompido
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    } else {
      Logger.log("Nenhum novo email para enviar!");
    }
  }
}

// Função para enviar e-mail com logotipo
function sendEmailWithLogo(emailDestination, subject, message, logoUrl) {
  // Busca o Blob do logotipo
  var logoBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(logoUrl).getBlob().setName("logoBlob");
  // Envia o e-mail
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailDestination,
    subject: subject,
    htmlBody: message + "<br><br><img src='cid:logo' align='middle' style='width:100px; height:100px;'>",
    inlineImages: {
      logo: logoBlob,
    },
  });
}

// Função para criar o acionador
function createTrigger() {
  // Esta função cria um acionador para executar a função sendEmail a cada semana, às 15 horas
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmail')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(15)
    .everyDays(7)
    .create();
}
```

Well, i did a basic code for my button at sheets:

```
function myButton() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Botão").getRange('A1:A1').setValue("CURT");
//Test to see if the button, when pressed, rotates and writes "CURT" in the spreadsheet

}
```

So, how do i run a google appscripts external script?
i'll be sending some images

[my button script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFA7w.png)

[my last code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SULug.png)

[my button sheet (Named "Botão")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZLbg.png)

I tried using some chatbots to help me with the coding and read some PDFs, tried watching youtube tutorials but they didn't help me that much.

Comment: I was able to solve this, i feel silly now